Why take $\cos az =$ Re $e^{iaz}$ instead of Re $e^{-iaz}$ in contour integration
While following through the method for computing $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos ax}{x^2 + 1}dx$ in Gamelin's Complex Analysis, (p201), the author proposed the method of setting $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{e^{iaz}}{z^2+1}$ and integrating around the semicircle contour

Then we have
\begin{equation} 
\displaystyle \oint_{\partial D_R} \frac{e^{iaz}}{z^2 + 1} dz
= \int_{-R}^R f + \int_{\Gamma_R} f
\end{equation}
Since $\displaystyle \left| \int_{\Gamma_R} f \right| \leq \frac{\pi R}{O(R^2)} \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$, the integral is then the residue of $f$ at $z=i$, which is
\begin{equation}
\oint_{\partial D_R} \frac{e^{iaz}}{z^2 + 1} dz = 2 \pi i \cdot \mbox{Res} \left[ \frac{e^{iaz}}{z^2 + 1}, i\right] = \frac{\pi}{e^a}
\end{equation}
The book has the restriction that $a >0$, and if I try to calculate with the assumption that $a<0$, i.e., taking $e^{-iaz}$ instead of $e^{iaz}$ for setting $f$, the calculation gives a different result, namely $\pi e^a$.
I think there is a reason why we cannot let $\cos az =$ Re $e^{-iaz}$, but I don't know why.
Any help would be appreciated.

If you take the semi-circular contour through the positive-imaginary half-plane, $|e^{-iaz}|$ becomes large.

On the face of it, it may not true in general that either $\cos az=\Re e^{aiz}$ or $\cos az=\Re e^{-aiz}.$

How can it?  $\cos az$ is often not real.

No reason why you can't choose the $\cos az = \Re e^{-iaz}$, but then the estimate on $\Gamma_R$ is wrong, so you'd have to chose a different contour (namely, you'd need to take the conjugate of $\Gamma_R$).

As Brian Moehring already stated, you would need to take the conjugate of your halfcircle in order for the contribution to become small when $R \to \infty $. Nothing wrong in doing this, BUT, it introduces one unnecessary complication. The residue theorem requires the closed integral path to be positive oriented, which in the alternative case forces the passage on the real line to be from $R$ to $-R$, giving the wrong sign on the answer . Thus, the natural choice is to take  $e^{iaz}$, $a>0$ as in the book.

In general,for any $a\in \mathbb R$,$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (a x)}{x^2+1} d x=\frac{\pi}{e^{|a|}}  $$
Whenever $a<0$, as $\cos x$ is even, therefore we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (a x)}{x^2+1} d x = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (|a| x)}{x^2+1} d x \\
= & \frac{\pi}{e^{|a|}}
\end{aligned}
$$
